# What's the impact of changing the appearance or costume of a bitizen?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What's the impact of changing the appearance or costume of a bitizen?
Are there any benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't noticed any changes in the game, no matter how many times I've changed someone's clothes.

But, I use their appearances to memorize their locations. It really helps when you need to find a bitizen for Bux or you do something with their jobs. I dress them up in such a way to create an association in my mind with the level they work on.

For example, all my bitizens in Rebo's Karaoke wear earphones, all Ithorian Food workers are dressed in orange/red. I have 80 bitizens, and I have memorized at least 80% of them.

On the downside, once you customize them, you can get a bit carried away and become attached to them, so evicting them gets very painful. :(

Comment: Or, you can't find a 9 level worker for Toydarian Toys who has a beard...

Comment: But you can find a male human 9 lvl and dress him up...